# What is Python equivalent of the C++ macro preprocessor directive?

Tags: python, c++, stack, preprocessor-directive

I have a repeated piece of code in my python code that I can’t factorize in a function because it analyses the call stack.

```
from traceback import extract_stack as es, format_list as fl

class Pmf

    def __init__(self,...):
        if not name: name = fl(es(limit=2))[0].split('\n')[1].strip().split("=")[0].strip()
        ....
```

In order to avoid copy pasting this code more than 10 times in my case, I would like to use some kind of macro preprocessor directive as in C++.

I don’t think that python Cython supports this feature but I was wondering if there was a python library or a workaround like a pycharm solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you factorise it in a function? If you write a function you will know exactly what its contribution to the stack trace is, and you can take it into account (e.g. by ignoring the top frame).

Comment: You are right, I just realized it. I just have to change limit=2 to limit=3 to be at the same  position in the call stack. Anyway, let's see if there is a macro like workaround ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No Python doesn’t have macros.
You can ‘simulate’ them by ‘messing’ with the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) but it isn’t exactly nice and is overall to be honest. I have never found a need for them - there are other ways to do what you might use macros for.

eg

```
macro='''
a=1
b=54
c=a+b
d=a-b
s = "hi k".split()
print(c**2+d**2, s)
'''
```

Output:

```
exec(macro)
5834 ['hi', 'k']
```

Comment: Thanks, it could be useful in the future but I was wrong thinking I can't factorize my code. I could by changing "limit= 2" to "limit= 3" .